# Missing drive when attaching database in SQL Management Studio 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

I'm trying to attach an external mdf file to my SQLEXPRESS instance from within the SQL Management Studio 2005. However, I'm unable to see the drive that the database file resides in under the directory browser within the "Locate Database Files" prompt.

Is there anything that is preventing the Management Studio or the SQL instance from recognising my drive? The drive itself is a local disk installed within my computer.

Comment: Can you see the drive from the OS in File Explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the permissions on the drive root. The folder browser runs under the SQL Engine identity, which may not have access to that drive.